# Change Breadth First Search to Depth First Search, N- Queen Solver

Tags: python, search, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, n-queens

I would appreciate if someone helps me understand how to change the Breadth First Search to Depth First Search, or which steps I need to follow.

The algorithm is basically in the next functions:

1. canPlace
2. getpositions
3. loopBoard

**CODE:**

```
import sys
import copy
from os import system

#Set the console title
system("title Michael Fiford - Breadth First N-Queen Solver")

class QueenSolver:
    #Store for the amount of queens we're placing, or table size
    tableSize = 0

    #The alphabet, for nice cell referencing on the output
    alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

    #The queue of possible moves that we will create and loop through
    queue = []

    #Whether or not the solver can be ran
    canRun = False

    def setup(self, queenNumber):
        #Set the number of queens/table size
        self.tableSize = queenNumber

        #Can run, so long as there are no errors
        self.canRun = True

        #Show error if there is no solution, or would take too long
        if queenNumber < 4:
            print "ERROR: A solution is not available for this few number of queens"
            self.canRun = False
        elif queenNumber > 13:
            print "ERROR: This solution would take too long to calculate, and your computer would probably run out of memory first!"
            self.canRun = False

    #Create an empty table
    def blankTable(self):
        table = []
        for row in xrange(self.tableSize):
            new = []
            for col in xrange(self.tableSize):
                new.append(0);
            table.append(new)
        return table

    #Place a queen in a table
    def placeQueen(self, table, row, col):
        #Copy the table, as python is annoying and will change both
        t2 = copy.deepcopy(table)
        t2[row][col] = 1
        return t2

    #The main program loop
    def loopBoard(self):
        #The column we are currently looking at
        col = 1
        #Loop while the queue isn't empty, and there are still move possibilities to explore
        while len(self.queue):
            #Create a new empty queue
            queue2 = []
            #Update status
            print col, "Queens Placed"
            #Loop the queue, looking for positions from each status
            #s is an array containing the current queen positions for this status
            for s in self.queue:
                #Get what moves are available from this status
                availableMoves = self.getPositions(s, col)
                #If we are placing the last queen, and there are solutions available, finish
                if col == self.tableSize -1 and len(availableMoves):
                    #Clear queue
                    self.queue = []
                    #Get the solution (or one of them, we only care about the first one)
                    s = availableMoves[0]
                    break;
                #Add the possible moves to the new queue
                #This a table containing all queens now placed
                if len(availableMoves):
                    queue2 += availableMoves
            #Replace the old queue with the new one
            self.queue = queue2
            #Increase Queen/col counter
            col += 1
        self.finish(s, col)

    #Get an array of moves that are available, given info about the current table, and the current column
    def getPositions(self, table, col):        
        #Create a row counter, and array to contain our position info
        row = 0
        possiblePositions = []

        #Loop all rows on the board
        while row < self.tableSize:
            #If we can place in this space
            if self.canPlace(table, row, col):
                #Add the table with the newly added queen to the list of possible moves
                possiblePositions.append(self.placeQueen(table, row, col))
            row += 1
        return possiblePositions

    #Check whether or not we can place a queen in a position, given the table and the row and col of the desired position
    #Return True if space is available
    def canPlace(self, table, row, col):
        # - Direction
        # Check left/right
        x = 0
        #Loop across the table
        while x < self.tableSize:
            if table[x][col]:
                return False
            x += 1

        # | Direction
        #Check up/down
        y = 0
        #Loop down the table
        while y < self.tableSize:
            if table[row][y]:
                return False
            y += 1


        # / Direction
        #Check up right Diagonal
        #We can start in the cell 1 up and 1 right of the cell in question, as we have already checked the actual cell in the above 2 checks
        x = row + 1
        y = col + 1
        #Loop up/right through the table
        while x < self.tableSize and y < self.tableSize:
            if table[x][y]:
                return False            
            x += 1
            y += 1
        #Check down left Diagonal
        #Again, not starting in the cell specified
        x = row - 1
        y = col - 1
        #Loop down/left through the table
        while x >= 0 and y >= 0:
            if table[x][y]:
                return False
            x -= 1
            y -= 1

        # \ Direction
        #Check up left diagonal
        #Again, not starting in the cell specified
        x = row - 1
        y = col + 1
        #Loop up left through the table
        while x >= 0 and y < self.tableSize:
            if table[x][y]:
                return False
            x -= 1
            y += 1
        #Check down right diagonal
        #Again, not starting in the cell specified
        x = row + 1
        y = col - 1
        #Loop down right through the table
        while x < self.tableSize and y >= 0:
            if table[x][y]:
                return False
            x += 1
            y -= 1

        return True

    #Output a table to a user, looking all pretty
    def display(self, table):
        #Max Number Length, so we can indent our table nicely later
        mnl = len(str(len(table)))

        #New Line
        print ""

        #Top of the table, E.g "     A B C D"
        print " "*mnl, "  ",
        for x in range(self.tableSize):
            print self.alphabet[x],
        #New Line
        print ""
        #Row spacer, E.g "   * - - - - *
        print " " * mnl, " *",
        for x in range(self.tableSize):
            print "-",
        print "*"

        #Row Counter
        #Print the actual table, with the Queens as 1's, empty space as 0
        #Also prefixed by the row number, E.g " 3 | 0 1 0 0 |
        x = 1
        for row in table:
            #If numbers are shorter than the largest number, give them extra spaces so the rows still line up
            extraPadding = mnl - len(str(x))
            #Show the number prefix, spaces, and | symbol, E.g " 6  | "
            print "", x, " "*int(extraPadding) + "|",
            #Show the value of the cell (1 or 0)
            for col in row:
                print col,
            #End of the row
            print "|"
            #Next Row
            x += 1
        #Show the same row spacer as at the top of the table, E.g "   * - - - - *
        print " " * mnl, " *",
        for x in range(self.tableSize):
            print "-",
        print "*"

    #We're done! Show output to the user
    def finish(self, table, col):
        #If we found the right number of queens
        if col == self.tableSize:
            print ""
            print "Total of", self.tableSize, "Queens placed!"
            print "Solution:"
            self.display(table)
        else:
            print ""
            print "ERROR: Could not place all queens for some unknown reason =["

    #Run the script
    def run(self):
        if not self.canRun:
            print "ERROR: Can not run"
        else:
            print ""
            print "Working..."
            print ""
            self.queue = self.getPositions(self.blankTable(), 0)
            self.loopBoard()

#Ask the user how many Queens they want to use
def ask():
    while True:
        print ""
        print "How many Queens would you like use?  [8]"
        input = raw_input()
        #Check if the input given is an integer
        if input.isdigit():
            return int(input)
        #If no input is given, use the standard 8
        elif input == "":
            return 8;
        print "ERROR: Invalid Input"

#Run the program
def run():
    #Instantiate the solver
    qs = QueenSolver()
    #While ask hasn't given a valid input
    while(not qs.canRun):
        qs.setup(ask())
    print ""
    #GO!
    qs.run()

#Prompt the user if they want to run the program again
def prompt():
    #Has valid input been received?
    while True:
        print ""
        print "Would you like to run the script again? Please enter Y/N  [N]"
        input = raw_input()
        #Check if the input given is Y or N
        if input == "Y" or input == "y":
            return True
        #Also accept an empty string in place of N
        elif input == "N" or input == "n" or input == "":
            return False
        print "ERROR: Invalid Input"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ""
    print ""
    print "  #######################################"
    print "  ## Breadth First Search Queen Solver ##"
    print "  ## By: Michael Fiford - COMF3        ##"
    print "  ## Date: 03/12/2013                  ##"
    print "  #######################################"

    #Run the script, and prompt them after if they want to run it again
    shouldRun = True
    while(shouldRun):
        run()
        shouldRun = prompt()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between DFS and BFS is in the way you are exploring the nodes of the graph.
In the DFS algorithm, you are first exploring the last node added into the stack (last in first out) whereas in the BFS algorithm, you are exploring it on the basis of first in first out (queue).

The resulting change is the code shoud be quite small: in the BFS algorithm, you could use a list to implement  the stack, appending new node at the top of the stack and then exploring them:

```
l=[]
while len(l)>0:
    new_node=l.pop()
    l.extend(new_node.get_neighbors())
```

The change is quite small to switch to the BFS algorithm: you switch from a stack to queue. This is implemented in Python in the collections module as a deque (with an efficient implementation of popleft (getting the first item of the list and remove it) and append (appending an item at the end of the queue):

```
import collections
l=collections.deque()
while len(l)>0:
    new_node=l.popleft()
    l.extend(new_node.get_neighbors())
```

Your code can be rewritten to fit with the previous description:

```
while len(self.queue):
        #Create a new empty queue
        #queue2 = []
        #Update status
        print col, "Queens Placed"
        #Loop the queue, looking for positions from each status
        #s is an array containing the current queen positions for this status
        s=queue.pop()
        #Get what moves are available from this status
        availableMoves = self.getPositions(s, col)
        #If we are placing the last queen, and there are solutions available, finish
        if col == self.tableSize -1 and len(availableMoves):
            #Clear queue
            self.queue = []
            #Get the solution (or one of them, we only care about the first one)
            s = availableMoves[0]
            break;
        #Add the possible moves to the new queue
        #This a table containing all queens now placed
        #if len(availableMoves):
        #    queue2 += availableMoves
        queue.extend(availableMoves)
        #Replace the old queue with the new one
        #self.queue = queue2
        #Increase Queen/col counter
        col += 1
```

Let me know if you need more explanations. Hope this helps.

Comment: in some ways, your answers helped me, but the real deal was to change BFS to DFS, can you give me some way to contact you?

Comment: what you need to change in the code above is queue which is going to be a collections.deque instance, and s=queue.pop() => s=queue.popleft().

Comment: I really thank you @Dvx, now I understand, but there's still one problem, if I do all this, there's no initial state to pop, it says: IndexError: pop from an empty deque

Comment: the first element in the stack/list should be the initial point where you are starting from. For exploration algorithms like BFS or DFS, what you need is an initial starting point, and for each node a way to get/build the list of it neighbors. I realize that there is a mistake in the previous code since with an empty list, you should never have entered the wile loop. please replace self.queue with queue and it will be ok.

Comment: You should say I ask too much, but now s is referenced before assignment, how do I fix this?

Comment: I can't get your point, since the code should read:
    while len(self.queue):
        s=self.queue.pop()
        ....